Can't access gcloud compute, DatabaseError
While trying to connect to a google cloud compute instance via iap-tunnel, I get this error message:
ERROR: gcloud crashed (DatabaseError): file is not a database
I tried connecting from an ubuntu CLI using
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel "comfy-ui-lab-$INSTANCE_NAME" 8188 --project=$INSTANCE_PROJECT --zone=$INSTANCE_ZONE --local-host-port=localhost:8188

for appropriate variables, as i did for the last few weeks. However instead of a password prompt, I just received the Error message.
Running
gcloud info --run-diagnostics

yields the same problem

Did answer below not resolve your issue?

Your gcloud client SQLLite db is probably corrupted. Running gcloud init should fix this.
If it does not, backup/clean the gcloud config dir first and then rerun gcloud init :
cd ~/.config
mv gcloud gcloud_bak
gcloud init

